How to add files with .csv file extension in C# scripts
My current script has an extension which downloads only .xlsx. I want to download .csv files also. The final download should include both .xlsx and .csv files:
string extn = ".xlsx";      

public void Main()
{
    // I have tried this: 
    var sourceDir = @"z:\sourcedir"; 
    var destDir = @"R:\targetdir"; 
    var pattern = "*.csv";

    foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir).GetFiles(pattern)) 
    {
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destDir, file.Name));
    }
}

But this is no solution; I want to embed in the older script that is:
string extn = ".xlsx";

public void Main()
{
    List<FileInfo> geFiles(string path, string extn, string BOT_StaggingFolder);
}


foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, ".").Where(file => file.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx") || file.ToLower().EndsWith(".csv")))
{
// Process the file
}
This code uses LINQ to filter out files that end with .xlsx or .csv, regardless of their case (lower or upper), ensuring that it captures all matching files in the specified directory.

How to add .csv file extension to this piece of code. How can I do that.@Coder
string extn = ".xlsx";

"To include both .xlsx and .csv files, you can update your pattern variable to use an array of patterns and then select files matching any of those patterns. Here's a quick modification to your code:

string[] patterns = new string[] { ".xlsx", ".csv" };
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir)
.Where(file => patterns.Any(p => file.EndsWith(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
.ToList();

Now, files will contain all files ending with .xlsx or .csv from the sourceDir directory."

Unfortunately for Directory.GetFiles you can only specify one extension. You can however try something like this:
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".csv") || s.EndsWith(".xlsx"));

foreach (string targetFile in files) 
{
  //Copy file as necessary
}

